# First number is enter then operators in calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my code of calculator,i want that firstly a number is taken as input and after that operator and at a time only one operator can be entered.Also in input,firstly numbers or digits must be taken and if operators are entered,it should not be taken or displayed.Operators like +,-,/,*,% and at a time only one operator must be entered.

```js
document.getElementById("AC").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
    
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("AC").innerHTML = "CE";
    }
```

```html
      <center>
    
        <form name="calculator">
          <div class=" outline">
    
            <table style="margin-top:40px;">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input name="displayresult" id="display" class="cal-input" placeholder="0" disabled>
         
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="0px" cellspacing="10px" style="margin-top:5px;">
    
              <tr>
                <td name="left" value="(" onclick="calculator.display.value += '('" class="cal-top">(</td>
                <td name="right" value=")" onclick="calculator.display.value += ')'" class="cal-top"> )</td>
                <td class="operator cal-top" name="percent" value="%" onclick="calculator.display.value += '%'">%</td>
                <td id="clear" name="clear" value="c" onclick="str = calculator.display.value.slice(0, -1); calculator.display.value = str" class=" cal-top"><font size="2" id="AC">AC</font></td>
    
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td name="seven" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'" class="cal-number">7</td>
                <td name="eight" value="8" onclick="calculator.display.value += '8'" class="cal-number">8</td>
                <td name="nine" value="9" onclick="calculator.display.value += '9'" class="cal-number">9</td>
                <td class="operator cal-top" name="div" value="/" onclick="calculator.display.value += '/'">/</td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td name="four" value="4" onclick="calculator.display.value += '4'" class="cal-number">4</td>
                <td name="five" value="5" onclick="calculator.display.value += '5'" class="cal-number">5</td>
                <td name="six" value="6" onclick="calculator.display.value += '6'" class="cal-number">6</td>
                <td class="operator cal-top" name="times" value="*" onclick="calculator.display.value += '*'">*</td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'" class="cal-number">1</td>
                <td name="two" value="2" onclick="calculator.display.value += '2'" class="cal-number">2</td>
                <td name="three" value="3" onclick="calculator.display.value += '3'" class="cal-number">3</td>
                <td class="operator cal-top" name="minus" value="-" onclick="calculator.display.value += '-'">-</td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td name="zero" value="0" onclick="calculator.display.value += '0'" class="cal-number">0</td>
                <td name="decimal" value="." onclick="calculator.display.value += '.'" class="cal-number">.</td>
                <td name="result" value="=" onclick="calculator.display.value = eval(calculator.display.value)" class="cal-result"><b>=</b></td>
                <td class="operator cal-top" name="plus" value="+" onclick="calculator.display.value += '+'">+</td>
              </tr>
    
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
    
    
      </center>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello! You've explained what you want, but you haven't actually asked a question. What step are you stuck on? What problems are you having with your code?

Comment: Fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/ohy6feg1/

Comment: i want something like this 2+4 or 10/5..... here you can see first there is an integer then an operator and then integer. I want same, input only start with integer and not with operator. And also only one operator can be inserted between two integers.  But in this code you can insert multiple operators everywhere,i want this to be removed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `onclick` on all symbols call a function instead of put text in the box:

```
checkIfValid('x')
```

Where *x* = the symbol for the specific `<td>` element eg:

```
<td class="operator cal-top" name="percent" value="%" onclick="checkIfValid('%')">%</td>
```

And the function can figure out whether or not to put the text in the box.

```
function checkIfValid(symbol) {
  if (calculator.display.value !== '') {
    var lastDigit = calculator.display.value.slice(-1);
    if (lastDigit == '%' || lastDigit == '/' || lastDigit == '*' || lastDigit == '-' || lastDigit == '+') {
      return false;
    } else {
      if (symbol == '=') {
        calculator.display.value = eval(calculator.display.value);
      } else {
        calculator.display.value += symbol;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
function checkIfValid(symbol) {
  if (calculator.display.value !== '') {
    var lastDigit = calculator.display.value.slice(-1);
    if (lastDigit == '%' || lastDigit == '/' || lastDigit == '*' || lastDigit == '-' || lastDigit == '+') {
      return false;
    } else {
      if (symbol == '=') {
        calculator.display.value = eval(calculator.display.value);
      } else {
        calculator.display.value += symbol;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<center>

  <form name="calculator">
    <div style=" width: 200px;height: 250px;border: 1px solid #D0CECE;">

      <table style="margin-top:20px;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="displayresult" id="display" class="cal-input" placeholder="0" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="0px" cellspacing="10px" style="margin-top:5px;">

        <tr>
          <td name="left" value="(" onclick="calculator.display.value += '('" class="cal-top">(</td>
          <td name="right" value=")" onclick="checkIfValid(')')" class="cal-top"> )</td>
          <td class="operator cal-top" name="percent" value="%" onclick="checkIfValid('%')">%</td>
          <td id="clear" name="clear" value="c" onclick="str = calculator.display.value.slice(0, -1); calculator.display.value = str" class=" cal-top">CE</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td name="seven" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'" class="cal-number">7</td>
          <td name="eight" value="8" onclick="calculator.display.value += '8'" class="cal-number">8</td>
          <td name="nine" value="9" onclick="calculator.display.value += '9'" class="cal-number">9</td>
          <td class="operator cal-top" name="div" value="/" onclick="checkIfValid('/')">/</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td name="four" value="4" onclick="calculator.display.value += '4'" class="cal-number">4</td>
          <td name="five" value="5" onclick="calculator.display.value += '5'" class="cal-number">5</td>
          <td name="six" value="6" onclick="calculator.display.value += '6'" class="cal-number">6</td>
          <td class="operator cal-top" name="times" value="*" onclick="checkIfValid('*')">*</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'" class="cal-number">1</td>
          <td name="two" value="2" onclick="calculator.display.value += '2'" class="cal-number">2</td>
          <td name="three" value="3" onclick="calculator.display.value += '3'" class="cal-number">3</td>
          <td class="operator cal-top" name="minus" value="-" onclick="checkIfValid('-')">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td name="zero" value="0" onclick="calculator.display.value += '0'" class="cal-number">0</td>
          <td name="decimal" value="." onclick="calculator.display.value += '.'" class="cal-number">.</td>
          <td name="result" value="=" onclick="checkIfValid('=')" class="cal-result"><b>=</b></td>
          <td class="operator cal-top" name="plus" value="+" onclick="checkIfValid('+')">+</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </form>


</center>
```

Comment: thanks dude,i want that when i click ")" ,multiplication should be done but it shows ")".